# How read an array in a txt file?

Tags: python, split, readline

I need to read these lines from a .txt file:

```
Turn  60 Player  -1
board: [[ 0  0  0  0  1  2  0  6 12  0  1  0  0  5  5 21]]
action p-values: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6326530612244898, 0.3673469387755102, 0.0]
nn: legal moves:[4, 5]
nn: select: 4
nn: db_lookup  0 0 0 0 1 2 0 6 12 0 1 0
nn: scores: [127, 127, 127, 127, -4, -5]
nn: best move selected
```

How can I extract the number in the array action p-values?

I need to create the same array.

This is my starting point:

```
with open(match, 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            if 'Turn' in line:
                line = next(searchfile)
                line = next(searchfile)
                if 'p-values' in line:
                    line.rstrip('\n')
                    fields = line.split(": ")
                    pvalues.append(fields[1])
```

But if i try to print pvalues I get an array with strings inside (included the \n). How can I have in pvalues and array with inside arrays of float?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ast library to convert string to list and also there is a bug  in your rstrip. See below.

```
import ast
pvalues=[]
with open('match', 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            if 'Turn' in line:
                line = next(searchfile)
                line = next(searchfile)
                if 'p-values' in line:
                    line=line.rstrip('\n')
                    fields = line.split(": ")
                    pvalues.append(ast.literal_eval(fields[1]))
pvalues

Result:
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6326530612244898, 0.3673469387755102, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first split based on `:` and then strip the new line character `\n` followed by using `literal_eval` to convert the string to list

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open(match, 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if 'Turn' in line:
            line = next(searchfile)
            line = next(searchfile)
            if 'p-values' in line:
                fields = line.split(": ")
                print (fields)
                pvalues = literal_eval(fields[1].strip('\n'))

print (pvalues)
# [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6326530612244898, 0.3673469387755102, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Accurately with `re.findall` function:

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as f:
    pvalues = []
    pat = re.compile(r'\d+\.?\d+')
    for line in f:
        if 'Turn' in line:
            next(f)
            line = next(f)
            if 'p-values' in line:
                num_str = line.strip().split(": ")[1]
                pvalues.append(list(map(float, pat.findall(num_str))))

print(pvalues)
```

The output (list of lists with float numbers):

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6326530612244898, 0.3673469387755102, 0.0]]
```